# clone() only partially doable; how to react?

Tags: idioms

Suppose we have a class-hierarchy whose base class `B` requires a `clone()` method to be defined in its derivations. Whilst this works perfectly for most of them there is this one derivation `X` that holds an **optional** reference to a resource/object that can only be referenced from one instance of `X`. Whilst the rest of `X` can be cloned without problems this reference would have to be set to null/nil/nullptr.

What is the correct way to handle this situation?

- `X::clone()` could throw an `UncloneableException`. Though this would be correct, it is not satisfying.
- Set the reference to null/nil/nullptr and leave no notice of it. The user of `X` has to know about `X`s "particularities".
- Require derivations of `B` to define `B::nearestClone()`: the user of `B` has to be aware that the return value might not be a 1:1 clone.
- Something else?

Comment: Question: could that single reference be made a class static on X?  Seems like the better solution.  Basically, rethink how class X works...

Comment: No, there are multiple different instances of that reference's target in the program at runtime.

Comment: Related reading: [Effective Java: Analysis of the clone() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540792/effective-java-analysis-of-the-clone-method)

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the language you're using, but I would suggest that one approach would be to have the base class should have a `protected` method `cloneBase`, and then for each class which could support cloning have a sealed concrete derivative which implements a covariantly-generically-typed cloning interface, with itself as the generic type parameter.  It may be useful to have this interface also include a method which implementations will use to return themselves, typed according to the generic parameter.

If `AnimalBase` would have no difficulty supporting cloning, but some derived classes may have non-cloneable objects, then `Animal` should be a sealed class which derives from `AnimalBase` and implements `ICloneable<Animal>`.  If `BirdBase` derives from animal, `Bird` would be a derivative of that which implements `ICloneable<Bird>`.  If `Phoenix` derives from `Bird` but can't support cloning, neither it nor any derivative would implement any `ICloneable` interface.

Using this approach, code which needs something that is cloneable and derives from `AnimalBase` could accept a parameter of type `ICloneable<AnimalBase>`; such a type could accept either `Animal` or `Bird`, even though those types are unrelated.  Code which needs to use an `ICloneable<AnimalBase>` as an `AnimalBase` could use its `Self` member.

Alternatively, one could implement an `IsCloneable` property/method and then have a `Clone` method which is only guaranteed to work if `IsCloneable` returns true.  Such an approach would provide no way for a type to indicate at compile time that it needed something that can be cloned, but it would avoid the need for extra sealed "leaf" types.  While there is some benefit to having methods express their requirements via their parameters, there is also benefit to avoiding the creation of otherwise-unnecessary types.

Answer (score 1):

Under the constraints of the question, I would have an interface such as this (pseudocode):

```
public interface Cloneable<T> {
  boolean isCloneable();
  T clone();
}
```

The `isCloneable()` method would return true if the current object can be cloned, while the `clone()` method would perform the actual clone. This is a kludgy hack for the fact that a subclass might not be cloneable despite implementing the `Cloneable` interface. If your programming language already provides a `Cloneable` interface you may need to add your own to make this work.

In fact this entire exercise serves to prove that a `Cloneable` interface is a bad idea. It places a constraint on any class that directly or indirectly implements the interface, *and potentially any class contained in `Cloneable` objects*.

Your question makes the assumption that cloning must be supported. However, the ideal way of copying an object is *not* to have a `Cloneable` interface, but to bake the idea of "copying" directly into a class *without* using the type system to define what is and is not cloneable. That is out of the scope of your question, but it might be worth exploring as a separate exercise (and perhaps follow-on question).

Comment: +1 for ranting on Cloneable.  I almost did that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one particular instance of X is the "alpha" X and is, in effect, a singleton.  Breaks some design principles but might still be reasonable.

The strict purist approach is that alphaX is not clonable, nor persistable, etc. so nobody can break the singleton contract.  This is actually tricky and has generated many articles and books. Your options are to make all Xs non-cloneable, or for just alphaX to throw an exception.  Can the user know if their particular X is the alpha?

However, if this is more like nodes in a tree where there is one special root node, but clone still makes some sense (whether you clone the parent and children is a good question) you could clone but set that reference to null.

So, "it depends".  Sorry that this isn't definitive.  :-)